# modmail not working AttributeError: 'ClientUser' object has no attribute 'send'

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

so i was making a discord bot and made a modmail system and got this error. can someone plz help and tell me where i am going wrong i searched many similar errors but there it was showing due to send_message which was changed in discord.py rewrite.

Error:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\\discord bot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\\discord bot\cogs\modmail.py", line 35, in on_message
msg = await message.author.send(embed=embed)
AttributeError: 'ClientUser' object has no attribute 'send'
```

My code:

```py
import discord
import asyncio
from discord.ext.commands import Cog
client = discord.Client()
sent_users = []
class modmail(Cog):

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
            print("modmail ready")


    @Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self,message):
        if message.guild:  # ensure the channel is a DM
            return

        if message.author == client.user:
            return

        if message.author.id in sent_users:  # Ensure the intial message hasn't been sent before
            return

        modmail_channel = discord.utils.get(client.get_all_channels(), name="modmail")

        embed = discord.Embed(color=0x00FFFF)
        embed.set_author(name=f"Olympia Gaming Modmail System",
                         icon_url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/icons/690937143522099220/34fbd058360c3d4696848592ff1c5191.webp?size=1024")
        embed.add_field(name='Report a member:', value=f"React with 1️⃣ if you want to report a member.")
        embed.add_field(name='Report a Staff Member:', value=f"React with 2️⃣ if you want to report a Staff Member.")
        embed.add_field(name='Warn Appeal:', value=f"React with 3️⃣ if you would like to appeal a warning.")
        embed.add_field(name='Question:',
                        value=f"React with 4️⃣ if you have a question about our moderation system or the server rules.")
        embed.set_footer(text="Olympia Gaming | Modmail")
        msg = await message.author.send(embed=embed)
        await msg.add_reaction("1️⃣")
        await msg.add_reaction("2️⃣")
        await msg.add_reaction("3️⃣")
        await msg.add_reaction("4️⃣")

        sent_users.append(message.author.id)  # add this user to the list of sent users

        try:
            def check(reaction, user):
                return user == message.author and str(reaction.emoji) in ["1️⃣", "2️⃣", "3️⃣", "4️⃣"]

            reaction, user = await client.wait_for("reaction_add", timeout=60, check=check)

            if str(reaction.emoji) == "1️⃣":
                embed = discord.Embed(color=0x00FFFF)
                embed.set_author(name=f"Olympia Gaming Modmail System",
                                 icon_url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/icons/690937143522099220/34fbd058360c3d4696848592ff1c5191.webp?size=1024")
                embed.add_field(name='How to Report:',
                                value="Send the ID of the person you are reporting and attach add a screen shot of them breaking a rule (can be ToS or a server rule).")
                embed.set_footer(text="Olympia Gaming | Report a member ")
                await message.author.send(embed=embed)

                message = await client.wait_for("message", timeout=60, check=lambda
                    m: m.channel == message.channel and m.author == message.author)
                embed = discord.Embed(title=f"{message.content}", color=0x00FFFF)
                await modmail_channel.send(embed=embed)


        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            await message.delete()



def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(modmail(client))
```

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/926071479706222622/926393218713649172/game_bot_-_Google_Chrome_12_31_2021_2_13_59_PM_LI.jpg

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to send a message to the bot itself (which it cannot do) this is because you have not correctly ignored yourself:

```py
# INCORRECT
if message.author == client.user:
    return
```

`client` here is not the same as your bot instance as it this is referencing a different instance defined on line 4 (`client = discord.Client()`). Instead what you want to do is ignore your instance via the use of `self` because you are passing in the bot instance via the `__init__` function, so it would be:

```py
if message.author == self.client.user:
    return
```

You should also remove that `client` instance on line 4 as you may get confused with the actual bot instance (`self.client`)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: This can be used for responding to the message in the same channel.

```py
await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
```

The below code is only valid if `message.author` returns a `User` or `Member`. The `ClientUser` model doesn't have `dm_channel` attribute or a `send()` method.

---

You need to specify that you want to send the message to the user's DM channel

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.User.dm_channel

```py
await message.author.dm_channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: msg = await message.author.dm_channel.send(embed=embed)
AttributeError: 'ClientUser' object has no attribute 'dm_channel' i am getting this error. also when i run the code the first half runs fine and i get a message the part that error occurs is is after the reaction part

Comment: Ah I misread. If you just want to reply to the message on the same channel you can use `message.channel.send()`

Comment: i changed line msg= await message.author.send(embed=embed) to msg= await message.channel.send(embed=embed) and what happened was the bot kept spamming the dm channel with the reaction message. so the problem lies in the transit somewhere after it send the react message the error occurs and the code stops going forward.

Comment: If it's spamming the channel it sounds like the bot is responding to its own message.

Comment: if u see the image i sent the first message it keeps on sending that itself. hmm probably yes its responding to it own message and by the time i add a reaction it spams it again.

Comment: But then why dosent author.send work coz that will detect for the person sending the message and not the bot.

Comment: Because `ClientUser` doesn't have a `send()` method. See the edit I made.

Comment: ok so what should be the solution should i use channel.send itself but find out a way to make the bot respond only to the author?

Comment: Try changing `if message.author == client.user` to `if message.author.id == client.user.id`

Comment: if message.author.id == client.user.id:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'

Comment: I assume `client.user` is what's `None`. The docs say it is `None` if it's not logged in. https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client.user So I guess add a `if client.user`

Comment: nope no output if i do that can you try out the code once?

Comment: I can't unfortunately. The `on_ready` method should be called once the bot is logged in. Do you see it print "modmail ready"? I've not used Cog, so I have no idea if it's causing anything weird.

Comment: nope nothing wrong with the cog. something with line 35 or so...